# Access Windows Drive From Linux in Dual Boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I have Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed on the same laptop. Three days earlier, I tried resetting Windows 10 completely but it got stuck at 9%. Turns out, it is a common issue. I forced shut down and tried resetting it again but same result. And now the Windows Installation files are corrupted.

I don't know the solution to repair the Windows so I started using Linux. I am a complete newbie to Linux.

I have 1 TB of total space and during installation of Linux, I allotted it only 100GB.
Since I can't use Windows anymore, I want to access the Windows drive and two other drives and have read and write permission.

Please, help me. I don't care about the Window 10 files.

Some information:

- Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 9CCAB439-717E-4C22-BB81-5D4E3694A471
    
    Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sda1        2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
    /dev/sda2     1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
    /dev/sda3     1288192  980335163 979046972 466.8G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda4   980336640 1206828699 226492060   108G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda5  1206831680 1695617517 488785838 233.1G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda6  1695619568 1926131717 230512150 109.9G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda7  1926133760 1934735359   8601600   4.1G Linux swap
    /dev/sda8  1934735360 1935656959    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
    /dev/sda9  1935656960 1953523711  17866752   8.5G Windows recovery environment
```

- Output of `sudo mount -a`

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
```

- About section in Settings

[image]

I have tried some solutions on Internet, but nothing worked and in all honesty I had no idea what I was doing or what I should do. I know nothing about Linux.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently [`ntfsfix -d`](https://www.mankier.com/8/ntfsfix) can help you clear the dirty flag. I wonder if it's better to copy all the files you want from the dirty filesystems (mounted read-only) to another drive, and then just re-format their partitions and copy the files back if desired.

Comment: Use Virtual Machines for what you are trying to do. Faster, Easier, Safer, More Robust, Way way fewer problems.

Comment: This is result of `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda5` --- `Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda5 was processed successfully.
`

Comment: Still no read and write permissions :(

Comment: Oh dear, did you run the command with the filesystem mounted? Maybe unmount and remount and see. (I *hope* that no further damages have been done. My bad.)  Btw write permission depends on a couple things, e.g. whether you are using the new "ntfs3" kernel driver or ntfs-3g, and what `uid=`/`gid=` mount option was used.

Comment: All hail @TomYan! I can't believe it worked! Thanks a lot. By the way, if it isn't too much of a bother, do you have any idea if I can completely remove Windows from my PC. Is it enough to just delete it's files from Windows drive. They are corrupted already.

Comment: As I said / implied, if I were you I'd just get all the files that I still want to another drive, and then delete all the Microsoft / Windows partitions. (**BUT, it seems that at least one of them is your Linux partition, unless you installed Linux to another drive; so DO NOT determine which to delete just by looking at the partition type.**) Also make sure that you keep the EFI partition (ESP), since it's likely used by your Linux installation as well.

Comment: And if you want to install Windows again later, you may want to delete the `Microsoft` directory under `EFI/` in the ESP first. Depending on your setup, the ESP might be mounted on `/boot` or `/boot/efi`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to fix this(This has happened to me once and this method works like a charm).
**Warning! All the Data will be wiped! Make sure to back up the data before starting.**

- Grab an unused USB. All the data is going to be wiped clean.
- Then follow [this guide](https://linuxopsys.com/topics/how-to-install-ventoy-on-ubuntu) to install ventoy into your USB
- Download the Windows 10 image from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO) and the ubuntu image from [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso).
- After both the images finish downloading, copy both the images into a partition named "Ventoy"
- Go to Google ,and search for the boot menu shortcut for your model of the laptop.
- Then press the power button. Continuously press the boot menu key until it shows up. choose the USB.
- Choose the windows iso
- Once it boots, proceed with the installation. once it reaches to the disks menu, delete both partitions. Then create a new partition with 1TB(Whole disk) and proceed with the installation on that disk partition.
- Then press the power button. Continuously press the boot menu key until it shows up. choose the USB.
- Now, choose the Ubuntu ISO.
- Proceed with the installation. Make sure to choose the option "Install ubuntu alongside windows" when asking where to install ubuntu.
- Once you finished installing, reboot and restore your backed-up files.Now you are done.

### If your computer, out of nowhere stops booting during this process, follow these steps.

**Step 1**- Create ubuntu install media

- Run these commands

```
cd Downloads
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```

Enter your password if required. Select the Image, then select the image downloaded, and click on "make startup disk". Wait for it to flash.

- Continue to the next step after it finishes flashing.

**Step 2** - Reboot your computer to the newly created USB

- Go to Google and search for the boot menu shortcut for your model of the laptop.
- Then press the power button. Continuously press the boot menu key until it shows up. choose the USB.
- Once it boots up, it should show up a menu. Click on Try ubuntu.
- Connect to your network
- Copy and paste these commands into a terminal (While booted into your live usb)

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common; \
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"; \
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

- Then press the window key and type boot-repair
- Open the app. There should be two buttons. Click on recommended boot repair. Follow the rest of the steps if any.
- Reboot your computer and you are finished